# NSTableView initial setup based on another table

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

This seems like it should be such a simple thing but I'm stumped. I have a view with two tableviews. The second table is filled with information based on the selection of the first table. The second table has to change the number of visible columns based on the selection in the first table.

To accomplish this I set the delegate for the second table and implemented tableViewSelectionDidChange. Works great so when the selection is changed in the first table the columns are updated in the second.

But here's the problem. When the view is first opened I need to set the visible columns of the second table based on the initial selection of the first but I can't seem to get the initial selection of the first table. awakeFromNib doesn't return the selection, nor does initWithNibName. I'm thinking these are fired before the first table is populated.

So here's the question. How do I get the initial selection of the first table when the view is presented for the first time.

Thanks all

Comment: How are you populating the first table view? Is it a data source or an array controller? Are you using Core Data?

Comment: Both tables are populated with Array controllers linked to core data but even when pulling the data from the Array Controller how would I trigger the change in visible rows for the second table? It seems that awakeFromNib fires before the tables are drawn.

Comment: BTW I've also tried to get the selection from the array controller directly but selectedRows returns 0 objects when called from awakeFromNib. IN .NET programming I would use the form load event but it doesn't seem like awakeFromNib works the same

Answer (score 0):

not knowing what you are using to feed data into the tableView, a rudimentary answer is `[tableView selectedRow]`. docs: *returns the index of the last row selected or added to the selection*.

however, the context of your question, speaks to the idea that you are unaware of needing a data source or array controller, as [bavarious](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557219/bavarious) responded.

if so, here is a [link](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSTableView) that may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. In case it might help anyone else or to satisfy anyones curiosity here's the solution.

Also, I apologize for not including enough information in the original question.

There are two tables managing tables of numbers, the first being table selection which is a master/detail type of view. When a table is selected the data for it is displayed in text fields, one of which is number of columns. My tableViewSelectionDidChange method grabs this number from the text field and sets the columns in the second table.

tableViewSelectionDidChange does indeed get fired on initial view load but it seems the text fields are not populated at that point since the text field is empty. It works fine after the view is loaded but on initial load the fields are empty.

So what I did is simply change the tableViewSelectionDidChange to get the value from the managed object of the array controller instead of the text field. Works great now.

Another roadblock down and more learning on my journey from .NET to Cocoa.

Thanks for the help and I will make sure I include ALL relevant info next question.